# Need tips when applying for a new Job in a Technology in which I didn't work in latest experience

Tags: job-change

I am currently working in Low Code RPA Technology Tool but I am interested in working as a developer in Python and React.

I am preparing myself for the interviews now accordingly since I had some previous experience in Java and Front end.

I have been working in my current job profile for past 1.5 years now but in between I have been doing some React and Python coding.
So my question is when applying for new job in my Interested areas like Python or React or Aws , basically Full stack developer what should I mention about my previous experience if they ask in interview ??

Should I be honest and tell them that I worked more in Low code tools but was preparing myself to find a job into programming due to my passion or should I try to see how my current Low code tools experience can be implemented using Python or programming and tell that as my experience in the further interviews...

I need tips from people who have changed their Job profiles on how did they manage their interview and what did they answer about previous experiences.

Comment: Did you write your CV like this? Difficult to read - needs editing and paragraphs.

Comment: Ohh no. I gave enter but still it didn't come in next line. Let me reformat

Comment: It's called RPA Technology, not Low Code RPA Technology. Don't sabotage yourself like that. Finding a job is hard enough. Stop underestimating yourself like that. Apply to many places. Some places, you won't pass their coding test. But some places, you will. And take a look at this guy's resume/youtube video below. Because of the technology he programs in, he's probably considered a "low code" developer by some. But does he mention that in his resume? Hell no!! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ht_-QxRPiE

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I think you got answer material right there sir :)

Comment: @DarkCygnus, Thanks, but anyone, please feel free to take this answer without crediting me. I borrowed many of the tips for my resume from the guy in the video I linked to.

Comment: Yes okay I won't mention low code in my resume but then O have to prepare my resume in a way that I have worked in technology in which I am searching job right instead of technology I am currently working in ??

Comment: I didn't want to give a full answer but just from experience. I recently changed jobs completely and went into a different field. I was honest about my experience, why I wanted the change and used stuff I'd done outside of work as examples. (e.g. building my own mini game in one of the languages required that I had no "professional" experience in) I got the job so it seemed to work. There are also loads of transferable skills so definitely highlight that

Comment: Hey thanks @Gamora Ur answer does help me and gives some confidence

Comment: Do you mean "Robotic Process Automation" ?

Answer (score 2):

First, be honest. Don't claim you have experience writing python/react code in production if you have not - because you'll be evaluated as "low learning ability".

Focus on what you are doing to prepare for these jobs. Some hiring managers put a lot of value on blog/github etc.

Focus on either python or javascript and brush up your coding interview skills.

You can emphasise how you gained experience on requirement definition, design, support etc. through your past work. Don't diminish your work when you talk about it - be proud and say you enjoyed it and learned a lot. Let the manager decide if they don't like that experience or not.

Finally, right now the hiring situation is so critical that you have a good chance.